# Spring scheduler batch + scaling batch

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring scheduler batch configurate sucessful and also a spring scaling batch configurated sucessful. How can I configure a scheduler batch with a scaling batch?
At the moment the step1 is not reachable:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The element [step1] is unreachable
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

Thanks!

```
<bean id="targetSync" class="org.jscsi.batch.TargetSync" />

<batch:job id="targetSyncJob">
    <batch:step id="step0">
        <batch:job ref="partitionJob"/>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet ref="targetSync" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

... targetSync ...

<!-- Scaling Spring Batch -->
<bean id="blockJscsiPartitioner" class="org.jscsi.batch.BlockJscsiPartitioner"
    scope="step" />

<bean id="taskExecutorPartition" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

<job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="masterStep">
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="blockJscsiPartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutorPartition" />
        </partition>
    </step>
</job>

<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet ref="blocksProcessor" />
</step>

<bean id="blocksProcessor" class="org.jscsi.processor.BlocksProcessor" />
```

Comment: I solved using <batch:step id="partitionStep" next="targetSyncStep">

Comment: Why do you have partitionJOb as a job instead of a step within targetSyncJob since it is only one step?  There isn't a need for both jobs.

Comment: you are right. I changed to this>      <batch:job id="targetSyncJob">
  <batch:step id="partitionStep" next="targetSyncStep">
   <batch:partition step="slave" partitioner="blockJscsiPartitioner">
    <batch:handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutorPartition" />
   </batch:partition>
   <batch:listeners>
    <batch:listener ref="stepListener" />
   </batch:listeners>
  </batch:step>
  <batch:step id="targetSyncStep">
   <batch:tasklet ref="targetSync" />
   <batch:listeners>
    <batch:listener ref="stepListener" />
   </batch:listeners>
  </batch:step>
 </batch:job>